# Bash file behaving diferently with Upstart service

Tags: upstart

I am trying to create a service that deploys an application from a git repository. For that, I execute a node JS script that listens to a port on the server, and each time a developer makes a push to the repo, it sends a request to this port on my server. Then, my nodejs script executes a bash script to deploy the application.

This works when I dot it manually:

1. I log in to my server with user `mmarteau`.
2. I go to the `~/deploy` directory and launch `node index.js`.
3. I make a request to my URL and my application deploys itself.

So I tried to make an upstart service to automate this. Here is my upstart service:

```
description "Service permettant le déploiement d'une application depuis bitbucket"
author "Mathieu Marteau"

start on filesystem runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
setuid mmarteau

exec /usr/bin/node /home/mmarteau/deploy/index.js
```

As you can see, I use the `setuid mmarteau` to launch the node script from the same user.

However, this does not behave the same. I run into permissions issues with the service, but not with the manual way. Where should I look to solve the problem? What am I doing Wrong?

Thank you very much for your answers and don't hesitate to ask me more information :)

PS: I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Could you be more specific in regards of permissions issues? Anything in `/var/log/upstart/nameOfTheService`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, there is nothing in the logs. However, I'm not so sure about the permission issues anymore. In fact it's a command in my bash file that is not being launch: `composer install`. I am going to try to launch it with the complete path...

Comment: The complete path doesn't change anything, however, a `sudo composer install` works. I'm not sure that this is the correct and secured solution tho

Comment: It's hard to say anything without knowing how your node application is working and what is done by bash script. What you are saying is that the problem is not related to upstart, right?